# Triggering an old build on buildbot externally?

Tags: httprequest, buildbot

I am running a [buildbot](http://buildbot.net/) buildserver. I have a job `my-job` that gets triggered each time a git push is made. All builds are kept and can be rebuild when I am logged in. The URL to an old build looks like this:

```
http://buildbot.internal:8010/builders/my-job/builds/924
```

Now I need to trigger an old build from a Java HTTP client implementation I have made (e.g http-get), is that possible?

I have not been able to find any documentation for this type of usage.

Answer (score 0):

In Buildbot-0.8.x, the best way to do this is to simulate a click of the "Rebuild" button in the web UI, which means POSTing the data that a web browser would POST for that form.

Comment: Yes that was my plan but how do write a post command from e.g command line/java that simulates a press on the Rebuild button?